# How to create a MigLayout for a simple minesweeper game?

Tags: clojure, miglayout, minesweeper, seesaw

I am working on a simple clojure minesweeper game, mainly to exercise the language a bit. The "core game engine" is ready and now I'd like to add a simple UI. I had a look into [seesaw](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw) and so far it worked quite nicely.

The only thing I am struggling with is the [mig layout](http://www.miglayout.com/) which I'd like to use. My idea is to have kind of the following layout:

```
 _______________________
[_________NORTH_________]
[   ][             ][   ]
[ W ][    FIXED    ][ E ]
[ E ][    SIZE     ][ A ]
[ S ][    BOARD    ][ S ]
[ T ][             ][ T ]
[___][_____________][___]
[_________SOUTH_________]
```

The north, west, east and south should grow in case the window is resized. The main panel should have a fixed size with all the buttons that represent the game board.

Before I read about mig layout I considered using a border-panel containing a grid-panel but as mentioned on the seesaw github page:

> Seesaw has rudimentary support for GridBagLayout in the seesaw.core/form-panel function. I don't recommend using this because it's half-baked and not as powerful as using MigLayout (seesaw.mig) or JGoodies (seesaw.forms).

I'd like to give MigLayout a try. My first try:

```
(defn make-border-panel 
[]
(mig-panel 
 :constraints ["fill" "[grow][][grow]" "[grow][][grow]"]
 :items [ 
       ["X"                  "shrink 0"  ]
       ["X"                  "shrink 0"  ]
       ["X"                  "shrink 0"  ]
       ["X"                  "shrink 0"  ]
       ["X"                  "shrink 0"  ]
       ["X"                  "shrink 0"  ]
       ["X"                  "shrink 0"  ]
       ["X"                  "shrink 0"  ]
       ["X"                  "shrink 0"  ]
       ["Minesweeper North"  "dock north"]
       ["W"                  "dock west" ]
       ["E"                  "dock east" ]
       ["Minesweeper South"  "dock south"]
      ]))
```

**UPDATE 1**

I'll ignore north, south, west, east for the moment and did the following to get at least the center board:

```
(defn make-button [x y]
   (button :id (format "cell_%d_%d" x y)
           :icon (clojure.java.io/resource "minesweeper/icons/button.png")))


(defn make-board
  [w h]
  (mig-panel 
      :constraints [(str "wrap" w) "[]" "[]" ]
      :items (for [x (range w) y (range h)]  
          (vector (make-button x y) "w 24px!, h 24px!"))))
```

Comment: OK. Did you have a question?

Comment: Actually, how I can achieve the mentioned border layout with a fixed size center. The "UPDATE 1" should be only an intermediate solution while I figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I do not really need WEST and EAST panel for my minesweeper game. My final layout looks like this:

```
 _____________
[____NORTH____]
[             ]
[             ]
[   CENTER    ]
[             ]
[_____________]
[____SOUTH____]
```

Center itself is another mig panel that contains the buttons representing the mines. The code in clojure looks like the following:

```
(defn make-layout
  [rows cols level]
  (mig-panel
   :constraints ["wrap1" "[center]" "[][]" ]
   :items       [[(make-info-panel)]
                [(make-board-panel rows cols level)]]))


(defn make-board-panel
  [rows cols level]
  (let [bg (button-group)]
    (mig-panel
     :constraints [(str "gap 0, wrap" rows) "[]" "[]" ]
     :items       (for [row (range rows) col (range cols)]
                    (vector (make-button row col level bg) "w 24px!, h 24px!")))))
```